# Airflow ignore LatestOnlyOperator

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I use `LatestOnlyOperator` as the first task of my scheduled DAG.
How can I rerun a dagrun which is **not the last**?

Answer (score 0):

`LatestOnlyOperator` [skips externally triggered dags](http://apache-airflow-docs.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/docs/apache-airflow/latest/_modules/airflow/operators/latest_only.html).

Go to *Tree View* in Airflow UI, click on the relevant dagrun (the upper circle, not any square), then click *Edit*, mark *External Trigger* and *Save*.
After that click on the dagrun again and choose *Clear*.

> ```
> # If the DAG Run is externally triggered, then return without
> # skipping downstream tasks
> ```